# reading USB port in Linux

Tags: c, linux, stream, usb, posix

I am writing a program to read data from a Bluetooth USB dongle. I am using Linux, so I suspect there may be a POSIX library to read from it, or perhaps there is a predefined file descriptor for each USB drive. How do I read a stream of data from a USB port in C?

Comment: do you want to read the raw device or the filesystem on that device?

Comment: I don't understand the question.  A "Bluetooth USB dongle" sounds to me like it's a bluetooth radio, which is probably supported already by the bluez stack.  But then you call it a "USB drive" which sounds like it's a storage device (which should also already be supported and mountable).  Finally you're asking to "read a stream of data" which sounds like you're trying to write a lower level piece of software.  So: what **exactly** is this device, and what are you trying to do with it?

Comment: It's a Bluetooth USB dongle. I suppose that "drive" was an erroneous choice of words, and it should have said "port". I will edit it accordingly. I am trying to get input from a PlayStation DualShock 3 controller.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most common way of interacting with  random USB device is [libusb](https://libusb.info/).  This provides low-level access to the device, so if you want something more complex (for example, if it's an actual USB drive with a filesystem on it), you might want to use some existing driver for the device rather than trying to interact with it directly.

Comment: How do I install that? I have the folder, but I'm not sure how to install the library.

Answer (score 0):

OK, given the answer above: the PS3 controller is, almost certainly, a HID device.  You pair with it like you do any other Bluetooth HID device.  It will appear as a joystick (or mouse, or keyboard, as appropriate) automatically once paired, with no software required on your part.  This site seems to have a guide, though obviously I haven't tested it: http://www.ydl.net/support/solutions/ydl_6.x/ps3_bluetooth_sixaxis.shtml